# How to change augmented faces click on image button (Google sceneform v1.15)

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am developing AR faces with the help of Google SceneForm API v 1.5.

When I am trying to change the face mask on the click of the image button, there is only showing the previous facemask. This means it is considering only the first clicked mask.

Please help with this. Thanks in advance!

```
faceNodeMap.clear();
     arFragment=null;
     arFragment = (FaceArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
     ModelRenderable.builder()
             .setSource(this, src)
             .build()
             .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                 faceRegionsRenderable = modelRenderable;
                 modelRenderable.setShadowCaster(false);
                 modelRenderable.setShadowReceiver(false);
             });

// Load the face mesh texture.
     Texture.builder()
             .setSource(this, src1)
             .build()
             .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture = texture);
     ArSceneView sceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();
     sceneView.setCameraStreamRenderPriority(Renderable.RENDER_PRIORITY_FIRST);
 Scene scene = sceneView.getScene();
 faceNodeMap.clear();
 scene.addOnUpdateListener(
         (FrameTime frameTime) -> {
             if (faceRegionsRenderable == null) {
                 return;
             }

             Collection<AugmentedFace> faceList =
                     sceneView.getSession().getAllTrackables(AugmentedFace.class);
             // Make new AugmentedFaceNodes for any new faces.
             for (AugmentedFace face : faceList) {
                 if(isAdded)
                     return;
                 if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {
                     AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
                     faceNode.setParent(null);
                     faceNode.setParent(scene);
                     faceNode.setFaceRegionsRenderable(faceRegionsRenderable);

                     faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
                     isAdded=true;
                 }
             }

             // Remove any AugmentedFaceNodes associated with an AugmentedFace that stopped tracking.
             Iterator<Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode>> iter =
                     faceNodeMap.entrySet().iterator();
             while (iter.hasNext()) {
                 Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode> entry = iter.next();
                 AugmentedFace face = entry.getKey();
                 if (face.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.STOPPED) {
                     AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = entry.getValue();
                     faceNode.setParent(null);
                     iter.remove();
                 }
             }
         });
```